# Записать в csv файл через метот Post

Tags: php

Нужно параметры формы, то-есть значение input с помощью метода post записать в csv файл в таком же формате.

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="SecondName"><br>
    <input type="text" name="mark"><br>
    <button>Send</button>
</form>

<?php

if(isset($_POST['SecondName'])){
  $secondName = $_POST['SecondName'];
} else {
  $secondName = "";
}
if(isset($_POST['mark'])){
  $mark = $_POST['mark'];
} else {
  $mark = "";
}
$params = array(
    "SecondName"=>$secondName,
    "mark"=>$mark
);

$file = '../csv.csv';     //сам файл
$fp = fopen($file, 'w');
foreach($params as $param) {
  fputcsv($fp, $param);
}
fclose($fp);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Записать в csv файл через метот Post

Как вариант, добавление в фаил CSV.

```
<form action="" method="post">
<input type="text" name="SecondName"><br>
<input type="text" name="mark"><br>
<button>Send</button>
</form>

<?php
// Переменные 
$secondName = "";
$mark = "";
// Только если форма отправлена и присутствуют оба поля
if(isset($_POST['SecondName']) && isset($_POST['mark'])){
    $secondName = filter_var($_POST['SecondName'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );
    $mark = filter_var($_POST['mark'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

    $file = '../csv.csv';    
    // Добавление в файл
    $fp = fopen($file, 'a');
    // Самый простой способ добавить строку csv
    fputcsv($fp, array($secondName, $mark));
    fclose($fp);
}
?>
```

---

[Доки fputcsv](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php)

[Доки Sanitize filters](https://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php)